# Remove scrollbar from child div

Tags: html, css, scrollbar, sticky

Here's my HTLM.

```css
.parent{
  border: 1px solid green;
}

.child1 {
  border: 1px solid darkgreen;
  height:200px;
}
.child2 {
  border: 1px solid pink;
  height:200px;
}
.child3 {
  border: 1px solid orange;
  height:200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent" style="max-height:500px;">
  <div class="child1"></div>
  <div class="child2"></div>
  <div class="child3" style="position: sticky; bottom: 0px;"></div>
</div>
```

I want parent div to have a max-height, so a scrollbar can appear. But I want it only on child1 and child2, not child3 as the div is sticky bottom.

Is there a way to have a scrollbar from parent that ignores a child div ?

Answer (score 0):

you can use the css propety overflow, to add or remove a scrolling bar.
[quelle](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_overflow.asp)

```
<div class="parent" style="max-height:500px;">
  <div class="child1" style="overflow: scroll;"></div>
  <div class="child2" style="overflow: scroll;"></div>
  <div class="child3" style="position: sticky; bottom: 0px; overflow: hidden;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Doing this, I still have a scrollbar on whole parent, and now have a second and a third one on my child1 and child2

Comment: @Valter So from what I'm understanding you don't want a scrolling bar on the entire parent but just for the divs inside it excluding the last one, is that correct?

Comment: Yes, exactly ! One single scrollbar for the divs inside except the last one !

Answer (score 0):

Okay for this you need a extra div for the scrollabil Elements.

I have added a 'wrapper-scroll-vertically' css class whitch is scrollabil and contains the elements that sould be scrolabil.

I have alsow changed the display type to [flex](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

hope that helps.

```
<style>
    .parent{
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
    border: 4px solid green;
    max-height:500px;
    }

    .child1 {
    border: 4px solid darkgreen;
    height:200px;
    width: 100%;
    }
    .child2 {
    border: 4px solid pink;
    height:200px;
    width: 100%;
    }
    .child3 {
    border: 4px solid orange;
    height:200px;
    width: 100%;
    }
    .wrapper-scroll-vertically{
        max-height: calc(100% - 200px);
        width: 100%;
        overflow-y: auto;
        overflow-x: hidden;
    }
</style>

<div class="parent">
    <div class="wrapper-scroll-vertically">
        <div class="child1"></div>
        <div class="child2"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="child3"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help ! Unfortunately, I can't add this extra div, as I'm trying to style components from a front framework I'm using :/. I don't have control over the htlm part...

Comment: Okay, @Valter that would have been usefull to knew earlyer, what frame work are you working with?

Comment: Sorry if it wasn't clear that I wanted to make it work for the specific html I provided :/. I use Kendo framework, for Blazor.